# How to add headers in quarkus reactive response filter?

Tags: quarkus

How can I add response header while using Quarkus reactive rest-easy response filter? I tried the following:

```java
    @ServerResponseFilter
    public void postResponseLog(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {
        log.info("app -> client ");
        ctx.getHeaders().add("x-trackingid", "a1234");
    }
```

The log messages shows up but the header is missing in the response. Any help or pointers here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ContainerResponseContext` instead of the `ContainerRequestContext`.

```
@ServerResponseFilter
public void postResponseLog(ContainerResponseContext ctx) {
    log.info("app -> client ");
    ctx.getHeaders().add("x-trackingid", "a1234");
}
```

Comment: Ouch! Thanks much